# PHP - How to build multiple input search

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, nette

I have a form with around 7 inputs and I want to let the user search according to the criteria he choosea.

So for example:
Inputs name can be:

- name
- age
- gender
- registration date

But my user wants to pick just first 3, so SQL query will look like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='.$name.' AND age= '.$age.' AND gender = '.$gender.'
```

Cool this work, but I am facing the problem of how to BUILD always different SQL query based on user input using MVC architecture.

My Idea was like:

```
// Syntax is from Nette Framework so please don't care about it, I basicly need logic for it in MVC

public function findMatch($name= NULL, $age= NULL, $gender = NULL)
{
    $selection = $this->database->table('table');
    if ($name) {
        $selection = $selection->where('name', $name);
    }
    if ($age) {
        $selection = $selection->where('age', $age);
    }
    if ($gender) {
        $selection = $selection->where('gender', $gender);
    }
    return $selection;
}
```

But this helps only with "OR" selection not with "AND". Please can someone help me figure out how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are considering a single `SQL SELECT` statement, you might want to try:

```
SELECT *
    FROM Table T
    WHERE (@name IS NULL OR T.Name LIKE '%' + @name + '%')
        AND (@age IS NULL OR T.Age = @age)
        ...
```

This will search base on the given criteria. Basically, on the `WHERE` clause, it tells you that:

if `@name` is `NULL`

- It will display all records with any name
- Else, it will return values with similar name only

Comment: Thank you KaeL, this is really helpfull so I mark it as "correct" how ever is there aa way how to check this in PHP because I see here some limits like if user add spaces to form.

Comment: If you are referring to the white spaces, you can trim the leading and trailing spaces of a string via `javascript`, not sure with `php`. If you need to remove white spaces in between the characters, one good option is to use `match` and `replace` via `regular expressions`, using `javascript` as well.